# How to set controls for ionic native video player

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i am using ionic 3 native video player to play video file in my app. It was working well but doesn't have any controls to play, pause, full screen etc. My problem is how can i set controls for the video player in ionic 3

Comment: Which plugin you are using to play video ?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/   plugin from this link

Comment: did you find any solution? the overlay is not working for me either. Because of Native layer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments This plugin not supported Video controls please check below issue open in Githb :

https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer/issues/6

Although you can create overlay view on your video screen and add your custom controls on it.

To add your overlay controls use below link.

Overlay on video view : https://medium.com/@anjana.pai.rathod/video-player-controls-on-a-ionic-app-f0f913a3e151

Hope this will helps to achieve your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried the above link  https://medium.com/@anjana.pai.rathod/video-player-controls-on-a-ionic-app-f0f913a3e151  but it was not overlaying on the video player